# SQL Year Plus Parameter returns nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am passing two variables in from a query string (which I verified that they are sending the correct values in, ?mon=4&year=11 lets say). When I try to run this query it returns no results.

```
@month varchar,
@year varchar

AS
Select *
From evn
Where (Month(EventDate) = Month(@month + '/1/11') AND Year(EventDate) = Year('1/1/' + @year))
Order By EventDate ASC
```

But if I change my Where to

```
Where (Month(EventDate) = Month(@month + '/1/11') AND Year(EventDate) = Year('1/1/11'))
```

Its work just fine, so Im assuming that my syntax is incorrect. As I said I have checked to make sure the query string is returning the correct values, and still nothing. Any help on this? Im using SQL Server 2005, Thanks

Comment: The @year is probably not set correctly.  Try changing the select to `select @month, @year` and see what it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you putting the year and month values into strings only to try to get out the same value again? Just send in the parameters as integers and use them straight off:

```
@month int,
@year int

as

Select *
From evn
Where Month(EventDate) = @month AND Year(EventDate) = @year
Order By EventDate ASC
```

Comment: I'm not sure how SARGable this would be. Does anyone know if this yields an full index/table scan or not? (I don't have SQL Server to hand and would love to know the resulting execution plan.)

Comment: @Dems: I was first going for a query that simply works, but you are right that calculating a date interval would definitely perform better.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I'd have preferred this in terms of layout / readability.

Comment: Interesting find on this, confirms perofrmance penalty of using MONTH and YEAR in this way :(  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/only-in-a-database-can-you-get-1000-impr

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested method isn't going to be very index friendly, perhaps use an alternative approach?

The following SQL will effeciently convert a date to the beginning of a month...
`DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, <a date>), 0)`

With that, you could pass in the month you are interested in, and for your query as...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  evn
WHERE
    EventDate >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @myDate),     0)
AND EventDate <  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @myDate) + 1, 0)
```

This avoid implicit conversion between string and dates.  More over, it ensures the mathematical manipulations are not done to the search field (EventDate), but instead are done only once, to the input parameter.  Not manipulating the EventDate field enables very efficient use of any appropriate indexes.